# calling two ajax pages in php using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('#btn_emials').click(function(e) {
        var emails=$('#txt_emails').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"../eoe/eoe_ajax.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{emails:emails},
            success: function(d){               
                if(d=="u"){
                    alert("Unfinished Task");
                }
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert("java error");
            }
        });
    });

    get_status();   
    setInterval( function() { get_status(); }, 5000 );


    function get_status(){

        $.ajax({
            url:"../eoe/live.php",
            success:function(data){
            alert(data);
                var v=data.split(",");
                var g=v[0];
                var b=v[1];
                var n=v[2];


                FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');
               var myChart = new FusionCharts( "Column3D.swf", "myChartId2", "400", "200", "0", "0" );
                 myChart.setXMLData('<chart>' +
                                    '<set label="Good" value="'+g+'"  color="CC99FF"/>' +
                                    '<set label="Bad" value="'+b+'" color=" #00BFFF"/>' +
                                    '<set label="Yet to be" value="'+n+'" color="#FF7F50"/>' +
                                    '</chart>');
                myChart.render("chartContainer1");


                tot=parseInt(g)+parseInt(b)+parseInt(n);
                d=parseInt(g)+parseInt(b);
                /*alert(tot);
                alert(d); */
                var p=d*100/tot;
                p=Math.round(p);
                p1=p*5;
                $('.pbar_fill').width(p1+'px');
                $('.perc').html(p+"%");
                $('.fin_no').html(d);
                //alert(p);
            },
             error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                 alert("live error");
                }    
        });
    }

});
```

here  for every 5 sec calling live.php page through get_status() function,if onclick on that verify button it will go to eoe_ajax.php page to verify emails which v sent to that page....but live.php is not execute untill eoe_ajax.php finished email verification....in eoe_ajax.php file v r using jar file inside eoe_ajax.php to verify email ids....

so i want to get live.php page for every 5 secs...pls help me...thanks...

Comment: How about clearing the interval when the verification button is triggered and then start it again when the ajax call eoe_ajax.php to finishes... ?

Comment: It's [working](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/X7uDR/) for me... changed alerts to logs (less annoying) Every +/-5 sec a log `live error` (404) and afther click `javascript error` (also 404 because the pages don't exist)

Comment: setInterval( function() { get_status(); }, 5000 );

Comment: setInterval( function() { get_status(); }, 5000 ); before onclick of verify  button it will load eoe/live.php page  for every 5 sec but after onclick of verify  button it will go inside tat get_status() function but it will not call eoe/live.php page

Comment: not working for me.. it is not executing eoe/live.php page untill eoe/eoe_ajax.php page execution finished when onclick of verify button

Answer (score 1):

Seems this might be a PHP issue. If you work with sessions with your application, there can be only one script accessing the session at the same time.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Answer (score 0):

Just use [async](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) on `false` after `$.ajax({`:

```
$.ajax({
...
async: false,
...
```